# What theory describes high temperature superconductivity more sucessfully?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

We know that there are so many theories on the high temperature superconductivity in cuprate. E.g. the U(1)/SU(2) gauge theory description of doped Mott insulator[Lee, Nagaosa, Wen], the phase-string theory of Zheng-Yu Wen, the renormailzed mean-field theory of Fu-Chun Zhang and TM Rice. Also, the antiferromagnetic spin-fluctuation theory, nematic fluctuation of CDW or SDW may be relevant.

My question is that what theory describes high temperature superconductivity more sucessfully?

It is known that a phenomenological theory of the anomalous pseudogap phase in underdoped cuprates, which is developed by Yang, Rice and Zhang, is sucessfully used in explaining many properties in underdoped cuprate. It seems that any reliable theory should reproduce the YRZ phenomenological theory.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119653/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7872/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406322/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147821/226902 ,  and this quite popular question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5332/226902