# What technological advance would a room temperature superconductor allow?

Tags: temperature, superconductivity, applied-physics, big-list

I have read a [recently published paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.12008) on arXiv where the scientists claim to have developed a superconductor material working at room temperature and pressure.

While it is clear that the results - if proven true - are preliminary, and that a lot of refinement would be necessary anyway, I am wondering what technological advances can we expect from such a discovery? Or, what technologies are currently impractical, impossible or unexplored due to the impracticality of currently industrially available superconductors?

Comment: I have read the site rules and I believe that this question is borderline in-topic (or borderline off-topic) for this site. Since I think this topic is super interesting, I opted to err on the less safe side, and let the community decide. If my interpretation of the rules was not on point, please accept my apologies.

Comment: For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room-temperature_superconductor and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406322/226902. Applications (the most obvious ones): electricity transport with no losses (efficient power grids), strong and convenient permanent magnets (e.g. for MRI), efficient magnetic levitation (magnetic flux pinning), plus probably a lot more in microelectronics.

Comment: IDK much about superconductors, but it might be hard to answer the question without knowing the physical properties and [_type of superconductor_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductor_classification). Physical strength is important because, many applications will have to do with magnetics, and a magnet must be physically strong to be useful. Electric motors and transformers potentially could be made much smaller than they are today if they used superconducting windings, but maybe not so much if the superconducting "wires" had to be bulked up with physical support structure.

Comment: Hype for LK99 is unjustified (not only, it is also a case of "bad science", see e.g. https://youtu.be/zl-AgmoZ5mo )

Answer (score 1):

If we get a practical room temperature superconductor, it really isn't possible to predict how the world will change. Some things are clear. Power will be transportable with less loss. But what new things will become possible or practical because of this is harder.

Think of wind powers ships around 1800. Now James Watt comes along and invents a steam engine. Here is a new source of power, different from wind, water, and animal. You can see there must be possibilities. But what used power in 1800? Mills, ships, carriages, plows, ...

Robert Fulton puts one on a boat. It is immediately clear that transportation of goods will become easier. It can travel upwind or upriver. You might think that a mill might be improved.

But you don't immediately see how it will be possible to make a machine do many other jobs that could only be done by hand. Could you make a steam engine saw a board? Certainly it could move a saw up and down, but that wouldn't help a carpenter. The industrial revolution wasn't immediately an obvious consequence.

The first steamship was crude. The engine made a shaft go up and down. This rocked a beam like a see saw (A "walking" beam). This made a paddle wheel rotate. It took a bit more thought to see that a rotating shaft and belts made were a better way to distribute power around a shop. It took improvements in making iron to make a boiler that wouldn't explode. And cast iron led to many other inventions.

You can apply the same thinking to large language AI models that have recently sprung up. You can see that once they get better new things will be possible. But you can't predict how life will change.

And it is the same for room temperature superconductivity.

Answer (score -1):

I am amateur myself when it comes to superconductivity and I apologise for the long response in advance. But I will be completely honest the claims about this one and the other one that was put on ArXiv https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.12037 are very very dubious and I am sure Hirsch or someone else will go through it with a finetooth comb and pick it apart.

For starters especially in the one you posted it seems like it was written with AI as a lot of the sentences did not make much sense like this one
"Consequently, why does LK-99 exhibit superconductivity at room temperature and ambient pressure? This is because the stress generated by the Cu2+ replacement of Pb(2)2+ ion was not relieved due to the structural uniqueness of LK-99 and at the same time was appropriately transferred to the interface of the cylindrical column." or this one "Josephson installed a thin insulator between superconductors and discovered tunneling through which current flows. Tunneling occurred between the superconductors(55). Likewise, if electrons are moved by tunneling between SQWs, the resistance will naturally be zero."

Also I will be honest I have never heard of a superconducting quantum well before like I don't know how that even works as a quantum well is usually deemed a potential well with discrete values, so I do not really understand what it has to do with superconductivity. Maybe they were thinking of the superconducting energy gap which is the energy required to break apart the Cooper Pairs, I am not sure.

Anyways the other main issues I have with both of them is I did not see a sign of superconductivity in either of them. The one you posted did not have even the most basic resistance vs temperature curve for showing superconductivity. The other paper showed something in figure 5 which also was not superconducting at all as it should not drop in resistance by 4 times, 10 times, 100 times it needs to go to zero Ohms using a 4 point probe which the graph does not. The video with a magnet coming near a material shows a material behaving like a diamagnetic material so not necessarily superconducting either. There are a lot of issues with the paper to be frank the mechanism they claim it works by is also quite confusing "The presence of the zero-resistivity region is evidence of an s-wave superconductor because a node-type superconductor with no-gap metal at node, such as dx2-y2 pairing symmetry has no zero-resistivity region due to increase of metal resistivity with increasing temperature" like that statement for example is leaving a lot to be desired and the main section on the mechanism uses some variant of BCS theory "A known theory to explain room-temperature superconductivity, including structural volume contraction, is BR-BCS, suggesting that divergence of the DOS, caused by on-site Coulomb repulsive interaction U increased by volume contraction, increases superconducting Tc over room temperature in the BR-BCS Tc".

Basically the papers make some very big claims but there is lot of lacking evidence and a lot of parts are written oddly like an AI bot or someone who does not completely grasp them has jammed them together so unless this gets reproduced with more conventional superconductor characterisation experiments, I think it is gonna stay in the non-published stage. Also these claims are made semi regularly like here are some others http://www.superconductors.org/5bMetals.htm and ironically this came out the same day https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-02401-2

Edit: I forgot to answer the technological advancements from potential superconductors working in ambient conditions. The first would be lossless powerlines that carry significantly more current that are also smaller, much more efficient electric motors, much more powerful magnets (think MRI's will become much more common, Fusion on the menu??), next would be much more common Josephson junctions for sensors, frictionless joints along with levitation, major improvements in Superconducting magnetic energy storage, some very fancy resonators etc etc basically things that use electricity will likely be impacted. Apologies Vladimir I essentially missed your entire question.

Comment: You didn't answer the OP actual question, which wasn't whether this specific room-temperature proposal actually works. He even suspected they don't. His question was what kind of technology will become possible once we have room-temperature superconductors. Will we have better computers? Flying cars? Cheaper electricity? Levitating frogs? :-) Or what?

Comment: We will know pretty soon whether this thing is real or not. The instructions to prepare it are pretty clear and the process relatively straightforward. As far as I can tell, the underlying physical argument is novel, but quite transparent and not obviously flawed.

Comment: By the way, prior to being posted on arxiv, the article or something very similar was apparently published in a Korean journal: http://journal.kci.go.kr/jkcgct/archive/articleView?artiId=ART002955269